# Disable download images colorbox popup

Tags: views, javascript

How can I disable "right click" in colorbox Popup so the visitor could not directly download images.

Comment: Please keep in mind that smart visitors will still be able to download images. But more important: we don't do "code from scratch" here. If this question is about code you attempted to write, share said code. If it's purely about code, not directly related to Drupal, it's off-topic here anyway. And if it's a feature request for a module, it's off-topic and should be posted in module's issue queue, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Copy Prevention](https://drupal.org/project/copyprevention) module.

This module will Place transparent image above all your images - this will protect your real images from being saved using context menu or drag-and-drop to desktop

More from module page:

> Anything you put out there in the Internet (public pages) is available for anyone else to copy and save/re-use. So if you really want your content to be safe and protected - do not put it online.
>
> But if you want you can try to protect your content/images and prevent/disable at least the most simple ways to copy it. In fact, anyone can "view source", check the browser cache for images, use "Print Screen" or "site copy" software, etc. - these things can't be disabled, but they require additional knowledge and skills than just selecting the content and copying it or dragging an image from browser window to the desktop.
>
> This module includes several different technical ways/methods to make copying/stealing information/images from your site harder than it usually is:
>
> This module includes several different technical ways/methods to make copying/stealing information/images from your site harder than it usually is:
>
> - Disable text selection
> - Disable copy to clipboard
> - Disable right-click context menu on all site content
> - Disable right-click context menu only on images ( tag)
> - **Place transparent image above all your images - this will protect
>   your real images from being saved using context menu or drag-and-drop
>   to desktop**
> - Protect/hide your images from search engine indexes so that your
>   images don't show up in image searches - add "noimageindex" robots
>   tag and disallow image files indexing in robots.txt